# how we do spyOn with a function referred in a async call

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Need help on Jasmine with angularjs :

I created spec for this below angular code. I could able to work with the service, if i don't have a data1 function. I need to know how we do spyOn with a function referred in a async call.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
    .factory("exampleService", function ($http) {
        var data1 = function () {
            return '/test';
        }
        return {
            data: function () {
                return data1();
            },
            getData: function () {
                return $http.get("/exampleUrl" + data1());
            }
        }
    });
```

Below spec code is

```
'use strict';
describe('service', function () {
    var $httpBackend;

beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
    $httpBackend.when("GET", "/exampleUrl/test1")
        .respond(200, {
            value: "goodValue"
        });
}));

afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

describe('exampleService successful http request', function () {
    it('.value should be "goodValue"', inject(function (exampleService) {

        spyOn(exampleService, 'data').and.callFake(function () {
            //done();
            return '/test1';
        });

        exampleService.getData().success(function (response) {
            expect(response.value).toEqual("goodValue");
        }).error(function (response) {
            //should not error with $httpBackend interceptor 200 status
            expect(false).toEqual(true);
        });

    }));
});
});
```

But i am getting exception like this

> Error : Unexpected Request : GET /exampleUrl/test